# When is a canvas filled?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying save a view to a bitmap without waiting for it to be rendered.
I request the rendering of a RecyclerView and then do:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
View view = activity.findViewById(R.id.my_view);
view.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
```

But if I save the bitmap right away it will be empty because the views in under my recycler view are still being drawn I guess.
I tired using the `ViewTreeObserver` and adding an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` but the problem persisted - that callback is called too soon.

How can I reliably wait for the bitmap / canvas to be filled? Is there a specific callback for that?

PS: no hard coded delays allowed :)

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to override the RecyclerView onMeasure method, and get the width/height values, if they are 0 they are just created, if they are greater, do you onDraw after the measure ends.

Comment: This is a test and I'm updating that RecyclerView constantly with new children saving a bitmap in every iteration. Wouldn't that approach only work for the first iteration when the Recycler view hadn't been drawn yet?

Comment: yes, other approach is to veryfi in onDraw if size = 0,0, if not print the result